# Different app behavior depending on the way it started - from play market or phone

Tags: android, android-intent

The problem occurs when I start my app from play market. Steps:

1. move from main activity to some other activity or fragment;
2. collapse app;
3. expand app.

After that steps I'll see my main activity again with the default fragment, it forgets all steps I did before collapse. This appears only after starting the app from play market when I kill the app and restart it from the menu - everything is ok.

Neither crashes on logs nor "don't keep activities" mode exists. It doesn't depend on the first start of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've localized and fixed this bug. The reason is that on some specific devices after starting from play market the app won't be registered in OS, so when I collapse and expand it, the app doesn't resume work, but OS starts new task for the app. That's why main activity appears as default (main activity **launchMode** is set for **singleTask**) - launch activity starts it and already created main activity gets *onNewIntent* method called.

I've fixed it with ugly hack - save somewhere (I save on App class) the flag, if MainActivity was already started and after application expanded check that flag in launch activity. If true - then finish that launch activity to prevent affection on previous main task.

Hope, I've described it clear enough to understand...